# How to group several JSON objects which contains array with same id together

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

Please help to figure out how can I group and display JSON objects.
Here's my example:

```
var result = [
   {
    "data":
           [{
             "id": 1,
              "name": "aaa"
          }]
   },
   {
    "data": 
          [{
             "id": 2,
             "name": "bbb"
          }]
  },
  {
    "data": 
          [{
             "id": 1,
             "name": "cccc"
          }]
  },
  {
      "data": [{
          "id": 3,
          "name": "ddd"
      }]
  },
 {
     "data": [{
         "id": 2,
        "name": "eee"
     }]
}, 
 {
    "data": 
           [{
            "id": 3,
             "name": "fff"
          }]
}
]
```

I want to group the name which have the same id using jQuery. 
Hope you can help me to solve this issue. I would be very thankful for this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: how exactly would you like the grouping?

Comment: Just a simple group by function where you for loop over all the objects, loop through the data and pull out into an object where the id are the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = [
   {
    "data":
           [{
             "id": 1,
              "name": "aaa"
          }]
   },
   {
    "data": 
          [{
             "id": 2,
             "name": "bbb"
          }]
  },
  {
    "data": 
          [{
             "id": 1,
             "name": "cccc"
          }]
  },
  {
      "data": [{
          "id": 3,
          "name": "ddd"
      }]
  },
 {
     "data": [{
         "id": 2,
        "name": "eee"
     }]
}, 
 {
    "data": 
           [{
            "id": 3,
             "name": "fff"
          }]
}
];

var groups={};

$.each(result,function(key,val){
    $.each(val.data,function(k,v){
        var id = v.id;
        if(groups[id]){

            groups[id]['name'].push(v.name);

        }else{
            groups[id] = {};
            groups[id]['name'] = [];
            groups[id]['name'].push(v.name);
            groups[id]['id'] = v.id;
        }



    });
});

console.log(groups);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jm3kr12w/1/

Comment: I want like this: `[Object, Object]
  0:object
   name: Array[2]
    0: aaa
    1: cccc
   id  : 1
  1:object
   name: Array[2]
    0: bbb
    1: eee
   id  : 2
  3:object
   name: Array[2]
    0: ddd
    1:fff
   id  : 3`

Comment: Thankz a lot. This is what I really want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope will work for you.

```
var groups = {};

    $.each(result,function(key,val){
        var data=val.data;
        $.each(data,function(k,v){
            var id = v.id;
            if(groups[id]){
                groups[id].push(v);
            }else{
                groups[id] = [];
                groups[id].push(v);
            }
        });
    });

    console.log(groups);
```

Output

```
{
    "1": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "aaa"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "cccc"
        }
    ],
    "2": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "bbb"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "eee"
        }
    ],
    "3": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "ddd"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "fff"
        }
    ]
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jm3kr12w/)

Comment: I want like this: `[Object, Object]
  0:object
   name: Array[2]
    0: aaa
    1: cccc
   id  : 1
  1:object
   name: Array[2]
    0: bbb
    1: eee
   id  : 2
  3:object
   name: Array[2]
    0: ddd
    1:fff
   id  : 3`

Comment: Could you please write the Expected Output JSON object

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var result = [
   {
       "data":
              [{
                  "id": 1,
                  "name": "aaa"
              }]
   },
   {
       "data":
             [{
                 "id": 2,
                 "name": "bbb"
             }]
   },
  {
      "data":
            [{
                "id": 1,
                "name": "cccc"
            }]
  },
  {
      "data": [{
          "id": 3,
          "name": "ddd"
      }]
  },
 {
     "data": [{
         "id": 2,
         "name": "eee"
     }]
 },
 {
     "data":
            [{
                "id": 3,
                "name": "fff"
            }]
 }
]
var tempArray = []

for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++)
{
    var o = null;
    var index = -1;

    for (var j = 0; j <tempArray.length; j++) {
        if (stackMethods.tempArray[j].Id == result[i].data[0].id) {
            index = j;
            o =tempArray[j];
            break;
        }
    }

    if(o!=null)
    {
        o.Names.push(result[i].data[0].name);

       tempArray[index] = o;
    }
    else {
        o = {};
        o.Id = result[i].data[0].id;
        o.Names = [];
        o.Names.push(result[i].data[0].name);
       tempArray.push(o);
    }

}
```